# Why does my query return an empty result?

Tags: sql

Here's the dataset:

- `Movie` (`mID, title, year, director`)
  English: There is a movie with ID number `mID`, a title, a release year, and a director.
- `Reviewer` (`rID, name`)
  English: The reviewer with ID number `rID` has a certain name.
- `Rating` (`rID, mID, stars, ratingDate`)
  English: The reviewer `rID` gave the movie `mID` a number of stars rating (1-5) on a certain `ratingDate`.

Here's the question: find the titles of all movies that have no ratings.

My answer: (returns an empty set)

```
 select m.title
 from movie m 
 join rating r on m.mid = r.mid
 where stars is null
```

Correct answer:

```
 select title
 from movie 
 left join rating using (mID)
 where stars is null
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my join? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query finds each `movie` record that *does* have a corresponding `rating` record — this is the meaning of `movie JOIN rating` — provided that said `rating` record has `stars IS NULL`.

The correct query finds each `movie` record that that *either* lacks a `rating` record *or* has a `rating` record with `stars IS NULL`.

The key difference is that your query will, as a first step, filter out any `movie` records without matching `rating` records (since these will fail the join), whereas the correct query uses a `LEFT JOIN` to prevent this filtering.

(Note that, even with a `LEFT JOIN`, this filtering can still happen if the `WHERE` clause is constructed poorly. For example, `WHERE stars = 'X'` would also filter out `movie` records without corresponding `rating` records, because only an existent `rating` record could satisfy the `WHERE`-clause. But with `WHERE stars IS NULL`, this problem does not arise, because `NULL` is the default value of `stars` when the join failed.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query for which title has no stars,
`"select title from movie left join rating on rating.mid = movie.mid where rating.rid is null"`
or you can use

```
select title from movie where mid not in (select distinct mid from rating )
```